# How to create one generic jsondatareader class for different JSON

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I have created customer json file as below:

[
  {
    "firstName": “test”,
    "lastName": “temp”,
    "age": 35,
    "emailAddress": “test@Gmail.com",
    "address": {
      "streetAddress": “test testing“,
      "city": “city”,
      "postCode": “12343546”,
      "state": “state”,
      "country": “cy”,
      "county": “abc”
    },
    "phoneNumber": {
      "home": "012345678",
      "mob": "0987654321"
    }
  },
  {
    "firstName": “tug”,
    "lastName": “kjk”,
    "age": 35,
    "emailAddress": “jhgj@Gmail.com",
    "address": {
      "streetAddress": “jh hjgjhg ,
      "city": “kjhjh”,
      "postCode": "122345",
      "state": “jhgl”,
      "country": “jaj”,
      "county": “jhgkg”
    },
    "phoneNumber": {
      "home": "012345678",
      "mob": "0987654321"
    }
  }
]

For the Customer JSON data file, I have created below JSON datareader class:

```
public class JsonDataReader {
    private final String customerFilePath = new ConfigFileReader().getTestDataResourcePath() + "Customer.json";
    private List<Customer> customerList;

    public JsonDataReader(){
        customerList = getCustomerData();
    }

    private List<Customer> getCustomerData() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        BufferedReader bufferReader = null;
        try {
            bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(customerFilePath));
            Customer[] customers = gson.fromJson(bufferReader, Customer[].class);
            return Arrays.asList(customers);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Json file not found at path : " + customerFilePath);
        }finally {
            try { if(bufferReader != null) bufferReader.close();}
            catch (IOException ignore) {}
        }
    }

    public final Customer getCustomerByName(String customerName){
        for(Customer customer : customerList) {
            if(customer.firstName.equalsIgnoreCase(customerName)) return customer;
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

Created POJO class as below:

```
public class Customer {
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
        public int age;
        public String emailAddress;
        public Address address;
        public PhoneNumber phoneNumber;

        public class Address {
            public String streetAddress;
            public String city;
            public String postCode;
            public String state;
            public String country;
            public String county;
        }

        public class PhoneNumber {
            public String home;
            public String mob;
        }

}
```

This is working fine so far as there is only one JSON data file, however I will create more JSON data files, so may be I have to create multiple POJOs for each one, but is there any way I can write common generic jsondatareader class for all those JSON files?

Answer (score 0):

A `class` (or an `Object`) is a *well defined* entity. By *well defined* I mean that its structure is known at compile time, and cannot be changed after that point.

Having to create multiple classes to represent multiple `JSON` documents is perfectly fine. So if you're worried about the amount of files you'll create, it's a non-problem.

But, if the `JSON` document structure will keep changing along with every request, there is no point in defining a series of classes. To handle totally dynamic `JSON` you should stick with what `Gson` offers you. That is `JsonElement` and its subclasses.

```
JsonElement
  > JsonArray
  > JsonObject
  > JsonPrimitive
  > JsonNull
```

That's all what is needed to describe a `JSON` object.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the case then why not convert JSON into a Map instead of a POJO! If you go POJO route then you will utilizing Jackson or GSon heavily  in your code base adding bunch of utility methods to iterate over every resulting JSonArray or JSonelements.